# Detect whether app was run via autorun.inf or doubleclick in explorer?

Tags: windows, winapi, autorun

i have a win32 api application residing on a usb virtual cd. Is it possible to determine whether it was run by windows executing autorun.inf or by user double-clicking the cd icon in explorer?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no direct way to detect that an application was run from an `autorun.inf`. the autorun stuff is launching the application as if it was launched by the user.

however, you can specify a *command line argument* in your `autorun.inf`, which will trigger a specific behaviour in your application. this command line argument is retrieved normally through `argv` or `GetCommandLine()`.

Comment: good idea, but isn't autorun.inf also parsed when a double-click on cd icon is done?

Comment: the 2 are undistinguishable: double-clicking a cd icon or inserting a cd both launch the autorun.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how double clicking the CD icon works, but how about detecting a command line used in the autorun.inf?

```
[autorun] 
open=yourapp.exe /viainf
```

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, double-clicking the CD icon in Windows Explorer just launches the autostart process chain.

As it is supposed to work this way and people expect it to behave like this, I would leave that path only for a *very* good reason.